# How to stop send form when refreshing page

Tags: php, yii

All says add these codes (`header(..); exit();`)

We have: `site.com/index.php?r=controller/index`, some form and fields with names "`filters[...]`" We submited form and then after refreshing the page form is getting sent again.

added in index.php:

```
if ( isset($_POST['filters']) ) {
    header("Location: site.com/index.php?r=controller/index");
    exit;
}
```

added in controller:

```
unset($_POST);
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [redirect()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#redirect-detail) or [refresh()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#refresh-detail) function after save/validate data:

```
if($model->save()){
    $this->redirect('site/login');
}else{
    $this->render('index',[...]);
}
```

or

```
if($model->save()){
    $this->refresh();
}else{
    $this->render('index',[...]);
}
```